# Removing WSDL differences while migrating from Axis2 to CXF

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, apache-axis

I am migrating my webservice publishing API from AXIS2 to CXF. CXF autogenerated WSDL is not similar to Axis2 WSDL. There are given below differences. As client sits somewhere else I am not able to test if these differences will affect Axis2 generated clients. How can remove these WSDL differences using CXF?
**CXF WSDL**

```
<xs:element name="test" type="tns:test"/> 
<xs:element name="testResponse" type="tns:testResponse"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="test"> 
        <xs:sequence> <xs:element name="doc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 
    <xs:complexType name="testResponse"> 
        <xs:sequence> <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>

<wsdl:portType name="TESTService">
```

**Axis2 WSDL**

```
<xsd:element name="test" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="testResponse" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<wsdl:portType name="TEST">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rif of **xs:elemntName** difference, remove '@WebParams' from web service input as it is accepting just a String not any complex object.

To remove **wsdl:portType** name difference, just added '@WebService(name) attribute. '@WebService' should be as per the specification order else cxf won't consider them in WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, adding an annotation of:

@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)

would do it.   You may also need to update "name" attributes of the @WebParam and @WebReturn params.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you completely. Which annotation will resolve what problem? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Are you referring to 'WebResult' instead of 'WebReturn'?